# how to search string in txt with PHP Stripos

Tags: php

I have a text file containing

number, zero, one

number, two, three

number, four, five

in a file called data.txt

I want to search for the number and tried this but doesnt seem to work

```
$file = 'domain.com/data.txt'; 
$searchnum = 'zero'; 

if (stripos($file, $searchnum) == true) { echo 'number found' }
```

Update 1.0
i tried this as well but it doesnt seem to pull the data on the txt file

```
$file = "domain.com/data.txt";

 $searchnum = "zero";
                if(exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($searchnum).' '.$file )) {
                echo "record found";
                }
                else {
                    echo "record notfound";

                }
```

Comment: You aren't searching the file contents. You're searching the path string. You need to use `file_get_contents` or something to open the file.

Comment: forgetting to use something should fall under as a typo; n'est-ce pas true?

Comment: After that you'll want `!== false` instead of `== true` though it will work with your sample data.

Comment: *"doesnt seem to work"* is not useful. What do you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Of course, if you search for `'zero'` inside `'domain.com/data.txt'` you're not gonna find it. Try to [read the content of the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and search into it.

Comment: @axiac the result is if the number is found a text would be displayed "number is found" else it would be just blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, you just need to pull the file contents.

```
$file = file_get_contents('./data.txt'); // you can use a full http address if your server allows it
$searchnum = 'zero'; 

if (stripos($file, $searchnum) !== false) { echo 'number found'; }
```

Comment: Note: http may not be available for them to use. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php states `A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.` Edit: This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47062280/1

Comment: I did $file = file_get_contents('domain.com/data.txt') but I am still not getting any result. Any idea?

Comment: @JeVic, yes, if you're using the domain name, then it has to include the protocol such as: `http://thedomain.com/data.txt`

Comment: sorry stack was blocking when I do that here is the exact code https://pastebin.com/NteT6EF0

Comment: @JeVic, change `$file = 'http://yourdomain.com/data.txt';` to `$file = file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/data.txt');`

Comment: last question does file_get_contents works will multiple domains?

Comment: @JeVic, it works on any site that allows it. If it's your own website and it's not working, you would have to adjust your CORS settings.

Answer (score 2):

`stripos()` returns the index of the searched string, or FALSE if it is not found.

So you would do `if (stripos($file, $searchnum) !== false) { echo 'number found'; }`

`!==` is used because you need to distinguish `false` from `0`.